# Laravel 5.7 - CSS and JS not loading using URL::asset

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I am new in laravel. I setup laravel 5.7 on my local system and put js and css into public folder but when hitting my site url on browser, site is not loading any css and js.

Site structure :

```
app
bootstrap
config
database
public
 -css
 -js
 -images
resources
 -views
    -includes
    -layouts
    -pages
routes
tests
vendor
index.php
server.php
.env
```

**Note : I have cut .htaccess and index.php files and put these on root to run site without public in path.**

Here is how I am calling url :
CSS :

```
{{ URL::asset('css/style.css') }}
```

JS :

```
{{ URL::asset('js/query-1.11.1.min.js') }}
```

When seeing source code, the url looks like this :

```
http://localhost/mysite/css/style.css
```

So can anybody help me out from this issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with "{{ asset('css/custom.css') }}"

Comment: @Ankit If you are still in development mode, I don't see a reason why you hate `public` in the URL? You can make a virtual host on your machine and start coding. When you go live, you can just point your domain to public folder itself. So, you would never get `public` in your domain URL at all.

Comment: @vivek_23 Thanks for the suggestion. Now I again put .htaccess and index.php into public folder and now everything is working. Thanks once again.

Comment: @Ankit Welcome. Now, for security reasons, put all your folders except for `public` folder outside of your `public_html` and edit `public/index.php`  with proper path for `$app` etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `asset()` helper prepends the base URL to the path you supply.

The base URL is the location of index.php (in this case: http://localhost/mysite/).

If you don't want index.php inside /public you will need to use public/ inside your asset path, like this:

```
asset("public/css/style.css")
```

Same for the js files, I hope you understand.

Comment: This will work on local development, but not in production when he will remove `public` from url

Comment: @cbaconnier can you explain further ? please.

Comment: We can assume @Ankit as to browse `localhost/mysite/public` since `index.php` is also in public folder. On production you want to browse `example.com` not `example.com/public` That's why laravel provide multiple way to serve without `public` folder exposed in the url. See my answer

Comment: @cbaconnier thats good, I'm not too much familiar about production server. But, one thing is whats the problem for the url of the css and js files since there will no public keyword in the route we define in our routes ?

Comment: You point the domain `example.com` to your folder `mysite/public` where the `index.php` is located at. Aside that `asset('public/css/... ');` will generate the url  `example.com/public/css/...` but Since your domain **already** point to `public` it will trow a 404 because your assets are in reality at the address `example.com/css/...`

Comment: @cbaconnier so what will be the line of code in link tag for css?

Comment: @Y.JoyCh.Singha you could test based on the environment, but it would work only on your setup. The [default call](https://github.com/laravel/ui/blob/master/src/Auth/bootstrap-stubs/layouts/app.stub#L20) is `asset('css/app.css')` and I did [an anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53746945/8068675) for this post on how to setup your local environment properly.

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 possibilites

- Use a tool like [Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/valet)
- Use [VirtualHost](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)
- Or the easiest, use the command `php artisan serve` in your project and browse
  http://localhost:8000 see [Local Development Server](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/installation#installing-laravel)

Edit : I forgot [Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/homestead)

Answer (score 0):

**FOR JAVASCRIPT :**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/query-1.11.1.min.js') }}"></script>
```

**FOR CSS :**

```
<link href="{{ URL::asset('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

**NOTE:** This will work if your directory structure is like this: */public/css/style.css* OR */public/js/query-1.11.1.min.js*

Comment: I tried this but it is not working. Actually I removed the .htaccess and index.php from public folder and put these files on root to run site without public.

Comment: You really shouldn't run your site from the root, this exposes your `.env` file

Answer (score 0):

When cut `.htaccess` and `index.php` files must give public folder as path. 
Try with this:

```
css
{{ URL::asset('public/css/style.css') }}
js
{{ URL::asset('public/js/query-1.11.1.min.js') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have directly put your css and js so you have to try this assets `href="{{ assets('')}}"` function.

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/invoice.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

and also js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/word.js') }}"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add new line in **.env** file

```
ASSET_URL=public
```

i fixed this issue this way.

Answer (score -1):

create .htaccess on your root folder
and write this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L,NC] 
</IfModule>
```